# MISRA. Write justification for exception

Tags: c, misra, coverity

I was wondering how can I write some "excuse" otherwise known as justification in C code for [MISRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) rules checked by [coverity](https://scan.coverity.com/). The only thing I know it is done by writing some C comment in source code but I can not find any example on the internet.
Can anyone help me with this subject? ;)

For example let's say I want to allow exception from Rule 42.7 on line 102 in my file source1.c. :)

Thank you and best regards.
Sorry for my english. :)

Comment: Each Coverity defect us prepended by the "tag". So you can suppress specific defects by adding the comment `/* coverity(tag) */`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Our qualitiy people frown on "silencing" static code checker warnings. They do not like the smell of "Yes I know there is a mistake here. Shut up.". Hence what I am used to and describe in my answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Well, for us the Coverity is giving a lot of pretty stupid "defects" that we must either suppress or mark as "intentional". This might be because the checkers and standards that were chosen for the scan are not really matching what we are doing.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I see. I wasn't aware that we are working for the same company. ;-) Yes, we excel in carefully choosing tools which are just not suitable for our purpose. I neglected to mention that a huge amount of effort is spent to configure, adapt and bend the tools to then kind of almost achieve our goal in spite of their actual design.

Comment: If you are "shutting up" the tool, there should be a justification... so the comment suggested by @EugeneSh. shoudl also include a reference to the appropriate Deviation ID

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this

```
/* In the code line following this comment, coverity's MISRA checks detect a
   violation of rule 42.7, because the code does indeed .... .
   After review with colleagues Name1, Name2 and Quality Assurance representative 
   Name3, 
   we agreed however that in this special case,  
   characterised by the fact that ....,
   this is not a problem for code quality or functionality, because .... .
   date
*/
```

Something very similar is mandatory where I work.

In cases like described by Eugene, where names cannot occur in source code which might get published/sold (i.e. in even more formal environments than I outlined), the documentation of who did the review could be in a separate, classified file, referenced by anonymising document IDs.

I am aware that most code checkers have a syntax to silence their warnings,
usually even to silence individual warnings.
I have learned to mistrust this feature, because it is too easy to silence something and then forget about it. To shed responsibility. To forget about the reasons for doing and for silencing this.
If you write the reason you cannot forget it and it can be rechecked later.
If you document (not necessarily name) the colleagues who decided this and e.g. a QA agreement, that can be based on rediscussing.
If you describe the characteristics of the code and the consequences for quality, then it can be noticed when the reason does not match the (modified) code anymore.

Comment: Then before the release (or after :) ) the folks from legal department are telling that it didn't pass their scan because it contains `Name1, Name2, Name3` :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I do not fully get your point. Are we talking personal data? Please elaborate. I could add a more "legalised" version referencing a review meeting, the participants of which and more detailed documentation is filed elsewhere and only referenced via a document ID.

Comment: Well, we are sometimes required to release our source code to some customers. Then anything like this needs to get cleaned up. This is of course not the case if source code is always internal.

Comment: Oh Brave New World in which customers get what they pay for, instead like with us, constant access to our versioning system.

Answer (score 0):

In MISRA a violation to a rule is known as a "deviation" from the MISRA compliance guidelines here you have how the violations/deviations shall be documented.

> Deviation records, a deviation record should include the following information:
>
> 1. The guideline(s) being violated.
> 2. A concise description of the circumstances in which a violation is acceptable.
> 3. The reason why the deviation is required
> 4. Background information to explain the context and the language issues
> 5. A set of requirements to include any risk assessment
>    procedures and precautions which must be observed.

Answer (score 0):

The formal term in MISRA-C would be *deviation* - and you may only deviate from *required* and *advisory* rules/directives. There's two ways you can implement MISRA-C:

- Either allow individuals to make deviations - potentially after peer review, or
- Don't allow individuals to make any deviations, but make every deviation project-wide and company-wide, in the internal coding standard.

If you allow individual deviations, you need at a minimum make source code comments at each deviating line. If you wish, you can integrate the deviation procedure with the company quality system (like ISO 9000), but it might become a bit burdensome then. (Which isn't necessarily bad, deviations should be exceptions, not the norm.)

I think it is much better to make a company-wide coding standard however. Not only is this less bureaucratic - it gives the rules more weight, since you can have a consensus among your colleagues how certain things should be handled. You are more motivated to follow rules set by your friends and/or boss.

Also, this prevents everyone who isn't a hardened C veteran - that is, the big majority, to make incorrect calls when to deviate and when not to. Particularly when the big majority of static analyser tools out there are of really sad quality, still.

Some MISRA rules are far from easy to understand, so just handing everyone a static analyser and expect them to work things out on their own from there is a very bad idea. It will likely do more harm than good if they haven't read and understood the MISRA document in detail. More so if you have a particularly broken tool.

You are also missing the chance of writing a simpler, briefer explanation in your coding standard. This is an excellent way of educating less experienced programmers, by explaining a single, local issue in the live code they are working with.

In your coding standard, you are expected to have a *compliance matrix*, basically a table pointing out how each rule is enforced. By the compiler, by the static analyser, by review etc. Here you can also list all company-wide deviations and point out where to find the rationale about that deviation. And finally, this allows you to filter out all rules company-wide by fine-tuning the static analyser and disabling the rules it shouldn't warn about.